# Iterating over class properties

Tags: c#, properties, iteration

I'm trying to iterate over the Color class' Color properties.

Unfortunately its not in a collection so its just a class with a bunch of static properties.

Does anyone know if its possible to iterate over a class' properties be it static or object based?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using reflection. Specific colors are defined as a static properties of the `Color struct`.

```
 PropertyInfo[] colors = typeof(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public);
 foreach(PropertyInfo pi in colors) {
     Color c = (Color)pi.GetValue(null, null);
     // do something here with the color
 }
```

Comment: I would add:

    if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(Color))

to future-proof against any new properties being added to Color.

Answer (score 2):

You might also be interested in this code

http://blog.guymahieu.com/2006/07/11/deep-reflection-of-properties-propertyreflector/

It provides an easy way to set/get properties by name. If you look into GetBestMatchingProperty you'll find the iteration over properties, that is done the same way as been posted before 
[Iterating over class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571982/iterating-over-class-properties/571988#571988)