# Is there a jQuery extend in c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
 var _Contact = new ContactLstModel { 
             ContactName="xxxxxx",
              EmailAddr="yyyyyy",
               ContactNo="ddddddd",
               SelectedContactType="dddd"
            };

 var _ContactOption= new ContactLstModel{
                 ContactType= new List<SelectListItem>(){
                 new SelectListItem{
                  Text="sss",Value="ddd"
                 }
                 }
            };
```

as you can see both are of the same model `ContactLstModel`. Now how do I combine both into one?

Like in jQuery, we have `$.extend(dest,source);`

Is there an equivalent in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a built-in equivalent of $.extend in C# and .NET 4.5.

However you can find many examples of people trying to achieve that kind of behavior using `reflection` in .NET. There are others who use serialization (JSON.NET etc.) to achieve similar behaviors . Another approach would be to use IOC containers like [Automapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/).

Here is an example how to merge your first object into the second object using [Automapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) IOC:

```
var expr = Mapper.CreateMap<ContactLstModel, ContactLstModel>().ForMember("ContactType", (conf) => { conf.Ignore(); });
var merged = Mapper.Map<ContactLstModel, ContactLstModel>(_Contact, _ContactOption);
```

With Automapper you can control how to map each single property from source to destination.

If you don't want external library dependencies, and want full control you can use a pure Reflection approach.

For example you could use something similar as the CopyValues method from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702603/merging-two-objects-in-c-sharp) and merge the second object properties with the first one using reflection.

```
CopyValues<ContactLstModel>(_Contact, _ContactOption);
```

So this line of code will copy the ContactType property values from the second object into the first one.

CopyValues uses reflection to loop through the properties of the objects:

```
public static void CopyValues<T>(T target, T source)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    var properties = t.GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.CanRead && prop.CanWrite);

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(source, null);
        if (value != null)
            prop.SetValue(target, value, null);
    }
}
```

Of course this does not support everything jquery extend does (merging, shallow and deep cloning into a new object etc.), but it can satisfy your current needs. You can extend on these principles and build a more comprehensive solution.

However have in mind that C# is not a language like Javascript, and the cost of doing reflection is much higher in C#, while in Javascript the properties of a prototype can be listed with a cheap `for-in` iteration, or with a call to Object.keys().

Comment: Reflection is a bit slower than methods dedicated to specific objects (like in Tomas Lycken answer) and allow less control, but it's the most generic way to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah. JQuery extend merges the properties automatically without specifying the names, so a reflection based approach is probably the closest he can get to that kind of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with an extension method:

```
public static class ContactModelExtensions {
    public static ContactModel Extend(this ContactModel first, ContactModel replacement) {
        if (!replacement.ContactsName.IsNullOrEmpty()) // or whatever criteria you want
        {
            first.ContactsName = replacement.ContactsName;
        }
        // similar assignment for all other properties

        return first; // since we return the first one, properties not set in override
                      // will be untouched
    }
}
```

Now, you can just

```
var extendedContact = _Contact.Extend(_ContactOptions);
```

to get it done.

Comment: Nice proposition, and faster than reflection, but this specific example will certainly not compile since "override" is a reserved keyword. I've suggested an edit for it.

Comment: @Richard: Thanks. That's what I get for typing code off my head without testing it, I guess :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use some frameworks for do it. For example with [ValueInjecter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ValueInjecter/):

```
    public class NoNullsInjection : ConventionInjection
    {
        protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            return c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name
                    && c.SourceProp.Value != null;
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public string a { get; set; }
        public string b { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a1 = new A() { a = "123" };
        A a2 = new A() { b = "456" };
        A c = new A();

        c.InjectFrom(new NoNullsInjection(),a1,a2); 
        // "c" now have a="123", b="456"     

    }
```