# In Unity, how to copy state of a GameObject to anther without allocating memory?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

I enconterd some problem when try to implent ObjectPool, please attention RefreshData method at bottom of the code block:

```
//Unity version 2022.3
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Pool;

public static class BulletPool
{
    private static ObjectPool<GameObject> Pool;
    private static GameObject BulletPrefab;

    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void InitPool()
    {
        BulletPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("BulletPrefab");
        Pool = new(
            createFunc: () => Object.Instantiate(BulletPrefab),
            actionOnRelease: (GameObject target) => target.SetActive(false),
            actionOnDestroy: (GameObject target) => Object.Destroy(target),
            actionOnGet: RefreshData
            );
    }

    public static GameObject Spawn(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 velocity)
    {
        GameObject spawned = Pool.Get();
        Rigidbody rb = spawned.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        spawned.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(position, rotation);
        rb.position = position;
        rb.rotation = rotation;
        rb.velocity = velocity;
        return spawned;
    }

    //A lot of data of it has changed like Light.color, Collider.isTrigger, 
    // Rigidbody.isKinematic, BulletComponent.isExploded, etc...
    public static void ReleaseBullet(GameObject toRelease) => Pool.Release(toRelease);

    private static void RefreshData(GameObject oldOne)
    {
    //here, Copy BulletPrefab's data to the oldOne, whatever what kind of data it has
    //including managed object fields, Unity native object fields, components enable status
    //just like Object.Instantiate(BulletPrefab) without allocating heap memory
    }
}
```

is this possible, or worth to do?

I tried read Unity manual, there's JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite, but it does not support engine type, and JsonSerialization.FromJsonOverride which said "does not support polymorphic unity object references".

Comment: what exactly is the use case for this? Exactly what kind of data do you want to copy there? I think you would be better by actually implementing the reset in the release and init in the get ... or you simply have a component on your bullet and implement `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` accordingly

Comment: @derHugo The 'bullet' here is just an example. The object pool type can be any type, and the initial state of the prefab usually changed by the artist, such as the type, count, and field values of components. To remember rewriting the Reset method after every time modify the initial prefab is a software engineering burden - that's why I am seeking a generic reset method that is independent of the initial state of the Prefab.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using *Reflection*, but it's going to be slow and counterproductive to your pooling performance gains. [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40403403/10060021) that does something similar to what you request (not exactly).

It's easier to just write a *Reset* function that copies values manually.

An improved, although more complex solution would be to use *code generation* using *Reflection* to write that function automatically, so you don't forget to copy any property or field.

Good luck!