# Ignore property when null using the new Net Core 3.0 Json

Tags: json, json.net, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

When using JSON.Net in ASP.Net Core 2.2 I was able to ignore a property when its value was null when serializing to JSON:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
```

But when using the new ASP.Net Core 3.0 built in JSON (System.Text.Json) I can’t find an equivalent attribute to ignore a property if its value is null.

I could only find JsonIgnore.

Am I missing something?

Comment: There is a thread on the [corefx github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40600) suggesting this get implemented but it looks like it's an all or nothing thing at the moment using `JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues`

Comment: System.Text.Json is meant for simple scenarios for now. It's main focus is speed and low allocations. You may have to use custom formatters or use JSON.NET fro more advanced scenarios

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Are you talking about JsonConverter? I have been looking for an example of how to do this but I can't find any ...

Comment: @SimplyGed Any idea how to accomplish this for now using System.Text.Json even if extra code is needed?

Comment: If you check the answers at this question of mine, they have some clever solutions using `JsonDocumnet` and `Utf8JsonReader` in `System.Text.Json`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835040/net-core-3-0-jsonserializer-populate-existing-object

Comment: @LGSon Sorry, not sure how can I solve my problem with your suggestion. I would prefer to define a custom converter for a class of type Envelope where the property created is. But I am not sure how.

Comment: Me neither, just wanted to share what they did. There could have been something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core: Remove null fields from API JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595027/net-core-remove-null-fields-from-api-json-response)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This was fixed on .Net 5

```
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
```

See the updates below

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41313

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30687

Answer (score 62):

While in **.NET 5 and later**, set [`JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.defaultignorecondition?view=net-5.0) to [`JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignorecondition?view=net-5.0):

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

I'm looking at **.Net Core 3.1**, where this should ignore null values

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
});
```

Note, the above isn't per property/attribute, although there is an attribute which may be helpful [`JsonIgnoreAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.1).

An alternative, to solve your problem might be a [JsonConverterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=netcore-3.1), information on how to write your own converter is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?view=netcore-3.1#register-a-custom-converter)

Comment: Now it's `options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull`.

Answer (score 13):

If you want property level control of ignoring null values during JSON serialization, for Net Core 3.1 you'll have to write a custom converter. There are [examples described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?view=netcore-3.1#conditionally-ignore-a-property) in the [Newtonsoft.Json migration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?view=netcore-3.1).

That is a big hassle for functionality that was declarative using Newtonsoft.Json. You can specify to use Newtonsoft.Json by [specifying as much in Startup.ConfigureServices()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project).

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

As the documentation notes, you'll need to add the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) package.

Comment: this answer is most likely the one everyone is after. As IgnoreNullValues only seems to apply to deserialization of an entry object. If you, like me, want to keep the same contracts for requests and response, adding newtonsoft back was the only option.

For instance my returned objects would ommit any field that was nullable, which unfortunately would break the "unofficial" contracts we had.

Answer (score 10):

Adding this to your startup should help although it's not per property and it's not an attribute.

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>{ options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true; });
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are still using Newtonsoft.Json in .net core 3.1, you want to have configuration like below.

```
services
   .AddControllers()
   .AddJsonOptions(options =>
   {
       options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
   })
   .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
   {
       options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
   });
```

Comment: At least for .NET Core 3.1, no need to call AddJsonOptions, but just:

```.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
});```

Comment: If you are using system.text.json then you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using System.Text.Json (.net 5.0) and you want to ignore all null
use WhenWritingNull condition:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(a =>
     {
        a.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;            
        a.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

For Minimal APIs running in DOTNET 7+ (probably 6 too) you can configure it globally simply as the Minimal API Tutorial's section [Configure JSON Serialization Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/responses?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-json-serialization-options) shows. Just use `Builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions()` as per the excerpt bellow:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => {
    options.SerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    // set other desired options here...
    options.SerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
    options.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL&DR**:  In DotNet 6 NullValueHandling has been **deprecated**. Instead, use DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull

```
   services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
     
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using .Net core 6 and System.Text.Json, then add this change in program.cs

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;

// if you want to remove $Id (metadata) from the response, add the below line
options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
```

Answer (score -3):

See the official migration guide [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Your service codes should look like this:

```
services.AddMvc(c =>
{

})
.AddNewtonsoftJson(
    options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;                      

            options.SerializerSettings.Error = (object sender, ErrorEventArgs args) =>
            {
               // handle error
            };
        }
    );
```

Comment: If you want property level control on ignoring null values and you don't want to go through the rather large hassle of writing custom converters then using Newtonsoft.Json is a valid approach.