# How do I append an JsonProperty to another JsonProperty

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.text.json

I have this JsonDocument which looks like this

```
string jsonString = "{\"year\": 0, \"class\": [], \"schools\": []}";
JsonDocument newSchema = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString)
```

And a bunch of JSON files, with these properties filed out.
Each of the JSON file have the same `year`, but contain information of one specific `class` and one specific `school`.  None of the them is the same beside the `year`.

I trying to create a one JsonDocument with all `class` and schools put together into one JsonDocument, but seem to have a problem with appending the JsonProperty together..

This is what I have tried so far:

```
using (JsonDocument newSchema = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString))
{
    List<JsonProperty> properties = new List<JsonProperty>();
    foreach(JsonProperty a in newSchema.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
    {
        properties.Add(a);
    }
    foreach (string classandSchoolDefinition in loadableSchemaDefinitions)
    {

        string schemaDefinitionAsJson = File.ReadAllText(classandSchoolDefinition );
        JsonDocument schemaJson = JsonDocument.Parse(schemaDefinitionAsJson);

        foreach (JsonProperty a in schemaJson.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
        {
            switch (a.Name)
            {
                case "year":
                    Console.WriteLine($@"({a.Name}+{a.Value}, {a.Value.ValueKind})");
                    break;
                case "class":
                    Console.WriteLine($@"({a.Name}+{a.Value}, {a.Value.ValueKind})");
                    break;
                case "school":
                    Console.WriteLine($@"({a.Name}+{a.Value}, {a.Value.ValueKind})");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I concat each the `Jsonproperty` value to one combined `newSchema`, and not keep the into one?
In this case I only want append an array to another array.

Comment: *I trying to create a one JsonDocument with all class and schools put together into one JsonDocument,* -- can you explain how you want to do this?  It's not clear from your question what the correct merging algorithm should be.  Maybe you could [edit] your question to include a couple of example files, and the desired result -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc -  `newSchema` contains no classes and schools, but each of json files contains an  EnumerableObject within the EnumerableArray fields class and school, Each of those EnumberableObject which can be found in the json files, has to be added to the EnumerableArray.

Comment: I need an AddEnumerableObjectToEnumerableArray(array, object) function

Comment: Could you share a couple of simple JSON examples as strings, showing your inputs and desired output?  Do you just want to concatenate the `"class"` and `"schools"` arrays?  What should happen if the `"year"` values differ?

Comment: I am not interested in `year` atm, but if they are different it should fail.

Comment: And yes, basically a concatenation, adding a new object to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach this with Newtonsoft.Json

For example, you have

```
var o1 = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'Name': 'Max',
  'Enabled': false,
  'Roles': [ 'User' ]
}");
```

and another object

```
var o2 = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'Enabled': true,
  'Roles': [ 'User', 'Admin' ]
}");
```

simply use Merge function like this -

```
o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    // to avoid duplicates
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
});
```

the result will be -

```
{
   "FirstName": "Max",
   "Enabled": true,
   "Roles": [
      "User",
      "Admin"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have too many dependency to `system.text.json` hence cannot use the `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: System.Text.Json does not have a mechanism to merge jsons because the existing JsonDocument, JsonElement APIs are read-only https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31433

Take a look at this answer, may it will help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574030/7436855

Comment: I ended up using the solution mentioned in the github issue.