# .NET Core/System.Text.Json: Enumerate and add/replace json properties/values

Tags: c#, system.text.json, asp.net-core-6.0

In an earlier question of mine I asked how to [populate an existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56835040/2827823) using System.Text.Json.

[One of the great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56906228/2827823) showed a solution parsing the json string with `JsonDocument` and enumerate it with `EnumerateObject`.

Over time my json string evolved and does now also contain an array of objects, and when parsing that with the code from the linked answer it throws the following exception:

```
The requested operation requires an element of type 'Object', but the target element has type 'Array'.
```

I figured out that one can in one way or the other look for the `JsonValueKind.Array`, and do something like this

```
if (json.ValueKind.Equals(JsonValueKind.Array))
{
    foreach (var item in json.EnumerateArray())
    {
        foreach (var property in item.EnumerateObject())
        {
            await OverwriteProperty(???);
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't make that work.

How to do this, and as a generic solution?

I would like to get *"Result 1"*, where array items gets added/updated, and *"Result 2"* (when passing a variable), where the whole array gets replaced.

For *"Result 2"* I assume one can detect `if (JsonValueKind.Array))` in the `OverwriteProperty` method, and where/how to pass the "replaceArray" variable? ... while iterating the array or the objects?

Some sample data:

Json string initial

```
{
  "Title": "Startpage",
  "Links": [
    {
      "Id": 10,
      "Text": "Start",
      "Link": "/index"
    },
    {
      "Id": 11,
      "Text": "Info",
      "Link": "/info"
    }
  ]
}
```

Json string to add/update

```
{
  "Head": "Latest news",
  "Links": [
    {
      "Id": 11,
      "Text": "News",
      "Link": "/news"
    },
    {
      "Id": 21,
      "Text": "More News",
      "Link": "/morenews"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result 1

```
{
  "Title": "Startpage",
  "Head": "Latest news"
  "Links": [
    {
      "Id": 10,
      "Text": "Start",
      "Link": "/indexnews"
    },
    {
      "Id": 11,
      "Text": "News",
      "Link": "/news"
    },
    {
      "Id": 21,
      "Text": "More news",
      "Link": "/morenews"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result 2

```
{
  "Title": "Startpage",
  "Head": "Latest news"
  "Links": [
    {
      "Id": 11,
      "Text": "News",
      "Link": "/news"
    },
    {
      "Id": 21,
      "Text": "More News",
      "Link": "/morenews"
    }
  ]
}
```

Classes

```
public class Pages
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Head { get; set; }
    public List<Links> Links { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

C# code:

```
public async Task PopulateObjectAsync(object target, string source, Type type, bool replaceArrays = false)
{
    using var json = JsonDocument.Parse(source).RootElement;

    if (json.ValueKind.Equals(JsonValueKind.Array))
    {
        foreach (var item in json.EnumerateArray())
        {
            foreach (var property in item.EnumerateObject())
            {
                await OverwriteProperty(???, replaceArray);  //use "replaceArray" here ?
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var property in json.EnumerateObject())
        {
            await OverwriteProperty(target, property, type, replaceArray);  //use "replaceArray" here ?
        }
    }

    return;
}

public async Task OverwriteProperty(object target, JsonProperty updatedProperty, Type type, bool replaceArrays)
{
    var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(updatedProperty.Name);

    if (propertyInfo == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
    object parsedValue;

    if (propertyType.IsValueType)
    {
        parsedValue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(
            updatedProperty.Value.GetRawText(),
            propertyType);
    }
    else if (replaceArrays && "property is JsonValueKind.Array")  //pseudo code sample
    {
        // use same code here as in above "IsValueType" ?
    }
    else
    {
        parsedValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(target);

        await PopulateObjectAsync(
            parsedValue,
            updatedProperty.Value.GetRawText(),
            propertyType);
    }

    propertyInfo.SetValue(target, parsedValue);
}
```

Comment: This looks like something .NET Core would do on [.NET Core Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for their `appsettings.json` files. Maybe checking their source code may help?

Comment: @LukeVo -- Yes, though what I need is what the linked answer does. I just need the minor update to handle an array. MS themselves suggest _custom converters_ or using the _Utf8JsonReader struct_, again there's an answer in the linked question. though it needs more work.

Comment: Do you look for solution that work for this specific case (i.e. you know the schema mostly stays), or a general solution for all kind of objects?

Comment: @LukeVo -- Using JsonDocument is a general way to deal with all kind of objects, and since the input format is JSON, I think it would be best to keep using that one.

Comment: @Asons Are you looking for a super generic solution or are looking for solution for your particular example?

Comment: @PeterCsala -- I am looking for a generic solution.

Comment: @Asons Have you tried making the Pages a generic class? The strip out the unnecessary arrays with a method. Something like Pages<T>

Comment: @Daniel -- Well, the `List<Links>` that I have is not unnecessary, and even if it were, there's still the need to be able to parse a JSON string that contains an enumerable `[ ... ]`  property.

Comment: @Asons Something like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/ySIzyd

Comment: @Daniel -- And how will that make the parse error I've posted about go away?

Comment: @Asons Then we can do something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#preserve-references This is for .NET 6. It has a similar pattern for .NET 3.1/5

Comment: @Daniel -- If you see something I don't, please provide an answer how that will solve my question. Use my sample JSON to make it easy to follow, and do note, I'm looking for a generic solution, not to solve my particular example, with e.g. a custom converter.

Comment: In .net configuration, replacements are made at the property level. So if that property is an array it gets replaced entirely. If you want to replace an array item in a generic way, you will have at least 2 scenarios: 1 for primitive types (where you can replace an item with only an index) and 2 for complex types where your underlying type either implement `IEquatable<T>` interface or you need to provide a comparer function explicitly.

Comment: @Eldar -- Yes, I am aware that array like types has its challenges. As I mentioned in a comment below, for a generic solution I will accept one that replace them entirely. For some of my own classes, where I really need the replace/add/update option, I will be able to setup a custom attribute/method to handle them properly.

Comment: @Asons The code for shallow copies from my answer you linked used verbatim works and produces Result 2: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bMNp57

Comment: @Asons The one for deep copies indeed throws the exception.

Comment: @V0ldek -- Yes, and it does for the `JsonValueKind.Array` property, hence the need to either loop that property using `EnumerateArray()` or deserialize it, which are the 2 things I asked about in this question.

Comment: @Asons I'm investingating this, will let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preliminaries

I'll be heavily working with the existing code from my answer to the linked question: [.Net Core 3.0 JsonSerializer populate existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835040/net-core-3-0-jsonserializer-populate-existing-object).

As I mentioned, the code for shallow copies works and produces Result 2. So we only need to fix the code for deep copying and get it to produce Result 1.

On my machine the code crashes in `PopulateObject` when the `propertyType` is `typeof(string)`, since `string` is neither a value type nor something represented by an object in JSON. I fixed that back in the original answer, the if must be:

```
if (elementType.IsValueType || elementType == typeof(string))
```

### Implementing the new requirements

Okay, so the first issue is recognising whether something is a collection. Currently we look at the type of the property that we want to overwrite to make a decision, so now we will do the same. The logic is as follows:

```cs
private static bool IsCollection(Type type) =>
        type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && 
        x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));
```

So the only things we consider collections are things that implement `ICollection<T>` for some `T`. We will handle collections completely separately by implementing a new `PopulateCollection` method. We will also need a way to construct a new collection - maybe the list in the initial object is `null`, so we need to create a new one before populating it. For that we'll look for its parameterless constructor:

```cs
private static object Instantiate(Type type)
{
    var ctor =  type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, Array.Empty<Type>());

    if (ctor is null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type {type.Name} has no parameterless constructor.");
    }

    return ctor.Invoke(Array.Empty<object?>());
}
```

We allow it to be `private`, because why not.

Now we make some changes to `OverwriteProperty`:

```cs
    private static void OverwriteProperty(object target, JsonProperty updatedProperty, Type type)
    {
        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(updatedProperty.Name);

        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (updatedProperty.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Null)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(target, null);
            return;
        }

        var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        object? parsedValue;

        if (propertyType.IsValueType || propertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            parsedValue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(
                updatedProperty.Value.GetRawText(),
                propertyType);
        }
        else if (IsCollection(propertyType))
        {
            var elementType = propertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            parsedValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(target);
            parsedValue ??= Instantiate(propertyType);

            PopulateCollection(parsedValue, updatedProperty.Value.GetRawText(), elementType);
        }
        else
        {
            parsedValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(target);
            parsedValue ??= Instantiate(propertyType);

            PopulateObject(
                parsedValue,
                updatedProperty.Value.GetRawText(),
                propertyType);
        }

        propertyInfo.SetValue(target, parsedValue);
    }
```

The big change is the second branch of the `if` statement. We find out the type of the elements in the collection and extract the existing collection from the object. If it is null, we create a new, empty one. Then we call the new method to populate it.

The `PopulateCollection` method will be very similar to `OverwriteProperty`.

```cs
private static void PopulateCollection(object target, string jsonSource, Type elementType)
```

First we get the `Add` method of the collection:

```cs
var addMethod = target.GetType().GetMethod("Add", new[] { elementType });
```

Here we expect an actual JSON array, so it's time to enumerate it. For every element in the array we need to do the same thing as in `OverwriteProperty`, depending on whether we have a value, array or object we have different flows.

```
foreach (var property in json.EnumerateArray())
{
    object? element;

    if (elementType.IsValueType || elementType == typeof(string))
    {
        element = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonSource, elementType);
    }
    else if (IsCollection(elementType))
    {
        var nestedElementType = elementType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        element = Instantiate(elementType);

        PopulateCollection(element, property.GetRawText(), nestedElementType);
    }
    else
    {
        element = Instantiate(elementType);

        PopulateObject(element, property.GetRawText(), elementType);
    }

    addMethod.Invoke(target, new[] { element });
}
```

### Uniqueness

Now we have an issue. The current implementation will *always* add to the collection, regardless of its current contents. So the thing this would return is neither Result 1 nor Result 2, it'd be Result 3:

```json
{
  "Title": "Startpage",
  "Head": "Latest news"
  "Links": [
    {
      "Id": 10,
      "Text": "Start",
      "Link": "/indexnews"
    },
    {
      "Id": 11,
      "Text": "News",
      "Link": "/news"
    },
    {
      "Id": 11,
      "Text": "News",
      "Link": "/news"
    },
    {
      "Id": 21,
      "Text": "More news",
      "Link": "/morenews"
    }
  ]
}
```

We had the array with links 10 and 11 and then added another one with links 11 and 12. There is no obvious natural way of dealing with this. The design decision I chose here is: the collection decides whether the element is already there. We will call the default `Contains` method on the collection and add if and only if it returns `false`. It requires us to override the `Equals` method on `Links` to compare the `Id`:

```cs
public override bool Equals(object? obj) =>
    obj is Links other && Id == other.Id;

public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();
```

Now the changes required are:

- First, fetch the `Contains` method:

```
var containsMethod = target.GetType().GetMethod("Contains", new[] { elementType });
```

- Then, check it after we get an `element`:

```
var contains = containsMethod.Invoke(target, new[] { element });
if (contains is false)
{
    addMethod.Invoke(target, new[] { element });
}
```

### Tests

I add a few things to your `Pages` and `Links` class, first of all I override `ToString` so we can easily check our results. Then, as mentioned, I override `Equals` for `Links`:

```cs
public class Pages
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Head { get; set; }
    public List<Links> Links { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => 
        $"Pages {{ Title = {Title}, Head = {Head}, Links = {string.Join(", ", Links)} }}";
}

public class Links
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj) =>
        obj is Links other && Id == other.Id;

    public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();

    public override string ToString() => $"Links {{ Id = {Id}, Text = {Text}, Link = {Link} }}";
}
```

And the test:

```cs
var initial = @"{
  ""Title"": ""Startpage"",
  ""Links"": [
    {
      ""Id"": 10,
      ""Text"": ""Start"",
      ""Link"": ""/index""
    },
    {
    ""Id"": 11,
      ""Text"": ""Info"",
      ""Link"": ""/info""
    }
  ]
}";

var update = @"{
  ""Head"": ""Latest news"",
  ""Links"": [
    {
      ""Id"": 11,
      ""Text"": ""News"",
      ""Link"": ""/news""
    },
    {
    ""Id"": 21,
      ""Text"": ""More News"",
      ""Link"": ""/morenews""
    }
  ]
}";

var pages = new Pages();

PopulateObject(pages, initial);

Console.WriteLine(pages);

PopulateObject(pages, update);

Console.WriteLine(pages);
```

The result:

```
Initial:
Pages { Title = Startpage, Head = , Links = Links { Id = 10, Text = Start, Link = /index }, Links { Id = 11, Text = Info, Link = /info } }
Update:
Pages { Title = Startpage, Head = Latest news, Links = Links { Id = 10, Text = Start, Link = /index }, Links { Id = 11, Text = Info, Link = /info }, Links { Id = 21, Text = More News, Link = /morenews } }
```

You can find it in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jaqO4A).

### Limitations

1. We use the `Add` method, so this will not work on properties that are .NET arrays, since you can't `Add` to them. They would have to be handled separately, where you first create the elements, then construct an array of an appropriate size and fill it.
2. The decision to use `Contains` is a bit iffy to me. It would be nice to have better control on what gets added to the collection. But this is simple and works, so it will be enough for an SO answer.

### Final code

```cs
static class JsonUtils
{
    public static void PopulateObject<T>(T target, string jsonSource) where T : class =>
        PopulateObject(target, jsonSource, typeof(T));

    public static void OverwriteProperty<T>(T target, JsonProperty updatedProperty) where T : class =>
        OverwriteProperty(target, updatedProperty, typeof(T));

    private static void PopulateObject(object target, string jsonSource, Type type)
    {
        using var json = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonSource).RootElement;

        foreach (var property in json.EnumerateObject())
        {
            OverwriteProperty(target, property, type);
        }
    }

    private static void PopulateCollection(object target, string jsonSource, Type elementType)
    {
        using var json = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonSource).RootElement;
        var addMethod = target.GetType().GetMethod("Add", new[] { elementType });
        var containsMethod = target.GetType().GetMethod("Contains", new[] { elementType });

        Debug.Assert(addMethod is not null);
        Debug.Assert(containsMethod is not null);

        foreach (var property in json.EnumerateArray())
        {
            object? element;

            if (elementType.IsValueType || elementType == typeof(string))
            {
                element = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonSource, elementType);
            }
            else if (IsCollection(elementType))
            {
                var nestedElementType = elementType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
                element = Instantiate(elementType);

                PopulateCollection(element, property.GetRawText(), nestedElementType);
            }
            else
            {
                element = Instantiate(elementType);

                PopulateObject(element, property.GetRawText(), elementType);
            }

            var contains = containsMethod.Invoke(target, new[] { element });
            if (contains is false)
            {
                addMethod.Invoke(target, new[] { element });
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OverwriteProperty(object target, JsonProperty updatedProperty, Type type)
    {
        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(updatedProperty.Name);

        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (updatedProperty.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Null)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(target, null);
            return;
        }

        var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        object? parsedValue;

        if (propertyType.IsValueType || propertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            parsedValue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(
                updatedProperty.Value.GetRawText(),
                propertyType);
        }
        else if (IsCollection(propertyType))
        {
            var elementType = propertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            parsedValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(target);
            parsedValue ??= Instantiate(propertyType);

            PopulateCollection(parsedValue, updatedProperty.Value.GetRawText(), elementType);
        }
        else
        {
            parsedValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(target);
            parsedValue ??= Instantiate(propertyType);

            PopulateObject(
                parsedValue,
                updatedProperty.Value.GetRawText(),
                propertyType);
        }

        propertyInfo.SetValue(target, parsedValue);
    }

    private static object Instantiate(Type type)
    {
        var ctor =  type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, Array.Empty<Type>());

        if (ctor is null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type {type.Name} has no parameterless constructor.");
        }

        return ctor.Invoke(Array.Empty<object?>());
    }

    private static bool IsCollection(Type type) =>
        type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));
}
```

Comment: Thanks...will study this within a couple of days, though it looks great and I've started yet another bounty :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, If you don't care how the arrays are written, I have a simple solution. Create a new JSON within 2 phases 1 loop for new properties and 1 loop for the updates:

```cs
    var sourceJson = @"
{
  ""Title"": ""Startpage"",
  ""Links"": [
    {
      ""Id"": 10,
      ""Text"": ""Start"",
      ""Link"": ""/index""
    },
    {
      ""Id"": 11,
      ""Text"": ""Info"",
      ""Link"": ""/info""
    }
  ]
}";
        var updateJson = @"
{
  ""Head"": ""Latest news"",
  ""Links"": [
    {
      ""Id"": 11,
      ""Text"": ""News"",
      ""Link"": ""/news""
    },
    {
      ""Id"": 21,
      ""Text"": ""More News"",
      ""Link"": ""/morenews""
    }
  ]
}
";
        using var source = JsonDocument.Parse(sourceJson);
        using var update = JsonDocument.Parse(updateJson);
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        // write non existing properties
        foreach (var prop in update.RootElement.EnumerateObject().Where(prop => !source.RootElement.TryGetProperty(prop.Name, out _)))
        {
            prop.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        // make updates for existing
        foreach (var prop in source.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
        {
            if (update.RootElement.TryGetProperty(prop.Name, out var overwrite))
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(prop.Name);
                overwrite.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                prop.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
        writer.Flush();
        var resultJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(resultJson);
```

Output :

```json
{
   "Head":"Latest news",
   "Title":"Startpage",
   "Links":[
      {
         "Id":11,
         "Text":"News",
         "Link":"/news"
      },
      {
         "Id":21,
         "Text":"More News",
         "Link":"/morenews"
      }
   ]
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PqBTnA)

Comment: Thanks...interesting solution. Will study it and see how I can make use of it. Still, I like solutions making use of System.Text.Json so I will give you the initial bounty.

Answer (score 1):

This is in case you want to use JSON-only solution though I think it's not that much better than Reflection solution. It absolutely covers less use cases than the default `JsonSerializer`, for example you may have problem with `IReadOnlyCollection`s.

```cs
public class JsonPopulator
{
    public static void PopulateObject(object target, string json, bool replaceArray)
    {
        using var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
        var root = jsonDoc.RootElement;

        // Simplify the process by making sure the first one is Object
        if (root.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Object)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException("JSON Root must be a JSON Object");
        }

        var type = target.GetType();
        foreach (var jsonProp in root.EnumerateObject())
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(jsonProp.Name);

            if (prop == null || !prop.CanWrite) { continue; }

            var currValue = prop.GetValue(target);
            var value = ParseJsonValue(jsonProp.Value, prop.PropertyType, replaceArray, currValue);

            if (value != null)
            {
                prop.SetValue(target, value);
            }
        }
    }

    static object? ParseJsonValue(JsonElement value, Type type, bool replaceArray, object? initialValue)
    {
        if (type.IsArray || type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IEnumerable<object>)))
        {
            // Array or List
            var initalArr = initialValue as IEnumerable<object>;

            // Get the type of the Array/List element
            var elType = GetElementType(type);

            var parsingValues = new List<object?>();
            foreach (var item in value.EnumerateArray())
            {
                parsingValues.Add(ParseJsonValue(item, elType, replaceArray, null));
            }

            List<object?> finalItems;
            if (replaceArray || initalArr == null)
            {
                finalItems = parsingValues;
            }
            else
            {
                finalItems = initalArr.Concat(parsingValues).ToList();
            }

            // Cast them to the correct type
            return CastIEnumrable(finalItems, type, elType);
        }
        else if (type.IsValueType || type == typeof(string))
        {
            // I don't think this is optimal but I will just use your code
            // since I assume it is working for you
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(
                value.GetRawText(),
                type);
        }
        else
        {
            // Assume it's object
            // Assuming it's object
            if (value.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Object)
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException("Expecting a JSON object");
            }

            var finalValue = initialValue;

            // If it's null, the original object didn't have it yet
            // Initialize it using default constructor
            // You may need to check for JsonConstructor as well
            if (initialValue == null)
            {
                var constructor = type.GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>());
                if (constructor == null)
                {
                    throw new TypeAccessException($"{type.Name} does not have a default constructor.");
                }

                finalValue = constructor.Invoke(Array.Empty<object>());
            }

            foreach (var jsonProp in value.EnumerateObject())
            {
                var subProp = type.GetProperty(jsonProp.Name);
                if (subProp == null || !subProp.CanWrite) { continue; }

                var initialSubPropValue = subProp.GetValue(finalValue);

                var finalSubPropValue = ParseJsonValue(jsonProp.Value, subProp.PropertyType, replaceArray, initialSubPropValue);
                if (finalSubPropValue != null)
                {
                    subProp.SetValue(finalValue, finalSubPropValue);
                }
            }

            return finalValue;
        }
    }

    static object? CastIEnumrable(List<object?> items, Type target, Type elementType)
    {
        object? result = null;

        if (IsList(target))
        {
            if (target.IsInterface)
            {
                return items;
            }
            else
            {
                result = Activator.CreateInstance(target);
                var col = (result as IList)!;

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    col.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (target.IsArray)
        {
            result = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, items.Count);
            var arr = (result as Array)!;

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                arr.SetValue(items[i], i);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    static bool IsList(Type type)
    {
       return type.GetInterface("IList") != null;
    }

    static Type GetElementType(Type enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable.GetInterfaces()
            .First(q => q.IsGenericType && q.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            .GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

}
```

Usage:

```cs
const string Json1 = "{\n  \"Title\": \"Startpage\",\n  \"Links\": [\n    {\n      \"Id\": 10,\n      \"Text\": \"Start\",\n      \"Link\": \"/index\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Id\": 11,\n      \"Text\": \"Info\",\n      \"Link\": \"/info\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";

const string Json2 = "{\n  \"Head\": \"Latest news\",\n  \"Links\": [\n    {\n      \"Id\": 11,\n      \"Text\": \"News\",\n      \"Link\": \"/news\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Id\": 21,\n      \"Text\": \"More News\",\n      \"Link\": \"/morenews\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";

var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Pages>(Json1)!;

JsonPopulator.PopulateObject(obj, Json2, false);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Links.Count); // 4
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj));

JsonPopulator.PopulateObject(obj, Json2, true);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Links.Count); // 2
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj));
```

Comment: Let me ask you this: If one were to deserialize the incoming JSON string and parse it using Reflection, how can one tell if e.g. an Int is actually set to a 0, given that an Int's default is also 0? And the same goes for many other property types. ... Do note, I'm not against Reflection, already using it in several other places.

Comment: Ah, you make the correct assessment. I totally forgot about non-null default values. Also when I said "better" I looked to performance side only. Yes, looks like this one is better although it may be worse in term of number of Collection types supported (you may need to write more logic).

Comment: Great...now we understand each other :) ... and I did remove my upvote at the other answer in favor for this one.

Comment: Thanks I learnt something as well. No hard feeling!

Answer (score 0):

After further consideration, I think a simpler solution for replacement should be using C# Reflection instead of relying on JSON. Tell me if it does not satisfy your need:

```cs
public class JsonPopulator
{


    public static void PopulateObjectByReflection(object target, string json, bool replaceArray)
    {
        var type = target.GetType();
        var replacements = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, type);

        PopulateSubObject(target, replacements, replaceArray);
    }

    static void PopulateSubObject(object target, object? replacements, bool replaceArray)
    {
        if (replacements == null) { return; }

        var props = target.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            // Skip if can't write
            if (!prop.CanWrite) { continue; }

            // Skip if no value in replacement
            var propType = prop.PropertyType;
            var replaceValue = prop.GetValue(replacements);
            if (replaceValue == GetDefaultValue(propType)) { continue; }

            // Now check if it's array AND we do not want to replace it            
            if (replaceValue is IEnumerable<object> replacementList)
            {
                var currList = prop.GetValue(target) as IEnumerable<object>;

                
                var finalList = replaceValue;
                // If there is no initial list, or if we simply want to replace the array
                if (currList == null || replaceArray)
                {
                    // Do nothing here, we simply replace it
                }
                else
                {
                    // Append items at the end
                    finalList = currList.Concat(replacementList);

                    // Since casting logic is complicated, we use a trick to just
                    // Serialize then Deserialize it again
                    // At the cost of performance hit if it's too big
                    var listJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(finalList);
                    finalList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(listJson, propType);
                }

                prop.SetValue(target, finalList);
            }
            else if (propType.IsValueType || propType == typeof(string))
            {
                // Simply copy value over
                prop.SetValue(target, replaceValue);
            }
            else
            {
                // Recursively copy child properties
                var subTarget = prop.GetValue(target);
                var subReplacement = prop.GetValue(replacements);

                // Special case: if original object doesn't have the value
                if (subTarget == null && subReplacement != null)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(target, subReplacement);
                }
                else
                {
                    PopulateSubObject(target, replacements, replaceArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype
    static object? GetDefaultValue(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsValueType)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using:

```cs
const string Json1 = "{\n  \"Title\": \"Startpage\",\n  \"Links\": [\n    {\n      \"Id\": 10,\n      \"Text\": \"Start\",\n      \"Link\": \"/index\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Id\": 11,\n      \"Text\": \"Info\",\n      \"Link\": \"/info\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";

const string Json2 = "{\n  \"Head\": \"Latest news\",\n  \"Links\": [\n    {\n      \"Id\": 11,\n      \"Text\": \"News\",\n      \"Link\": \"/news\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Id\": 21,\n      \"Text\": \"More News\",\n      \"Link\": \"/morenews\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";

var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Pages>(Json1)!;

JsonPopulator.PopulateObjectByReflection(obj, Json2, false);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Links.Count); // 4

JsonPopulator.PopulateObjectByReflection(obj, Json2, true);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Links.Count); // 2
```

The solution even works when I replace `List<Links>` with array `Links[]`:

```cs
public class Pages
{
    // ...
    public Links[] Links { get; set; }
}

JsonPopulator.PopulateObjectByReflection(obj, Json2, false);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Links.Length); // 4

JsonPopulator.PopulateObjectByReflection(obj, Json2, true);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Links.Length); // 2
```

---

*Abandoned solution:*

I think a simple solution would be to include the parent and its current property info. One reason is that not every `IEnumerable` is mutable anyway (Array for example) so you will want to replace it even with `replaceArray` being false.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json;

const string Json1 = @"
    {
        ""Bars"": [
            { ""Value"": 0 },
            { ""Value"": 1 }
        ]
    }
";

const string Json2 = @"
    {
        ""Bars"": [
            { ""Value"": 2 },
            { ""Value"": 3 }
        ]
    }
";

var foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(Json1)!;

PopulateObject(foo, Json2, false);
Console.WriteLine(foo.Bars.Count); // 4

PopulateObject(foo, Json2, true);
Console.WriteLine(foo.Bars.Count); // 2

static void PopulateObject(object target, string replacement, bool replaceArray)
{

    using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(Json2);
    var root = doc.RootElement;

    PopulateObjectWithJson(target, root, replaceArray, null, null);
}

static void PopulateObjectWithJson(object target, JsonElement el, bool replaceArray, object? parent, PropertyInfo? parentProp)
{
    // There should be other checks
    switch (el.ValueKind)
    {
        case JsonValueKind.Object:
            // Just simple check here, you may want more logic
            var props = target.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(q => q.Name);

            foreach (var jsonProp in el.EnumerateObject())
            {
                if (props.TryGetValue(jsonProp.Name, out var prop))
                {
                    var subTarget = prop.GetValue(target);

                    // You may need to check for null etc here
                    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(subTarget);

                    PopulateObjectWithJson(subTarget, jsonProp.Value, replaceArray, target, prop);
                }
            }

            break;
        case JsonValueKind.Array:
            var parsedItems = new List<object>();
            foreach (var item in el.EnumerateArray())
            {
                // Parse your value here, I will just assume the type for simplicity
                var bar = new Bar()
                {
                    Value = item.GetProperty(nameof(Bar.Value)).GetInt32(),
                };

                parsedItems.Add(bar);
            }

            IEnumerable<object> finalItems = parsedItems;
            if (!replaceArray)
            {
                finalItems = ((IEnumerable<object>)target).Concat(parsedItems);
            }

            // Parse your list into List/Array/Collection/etc
            // You need reflection here as well
            var list = finalItems.Cast<Bar>().ToList();
            parentProp?.SetValue(parent, list);

            break;
        default:
            // Should handle for other types
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Foo
{

    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; } = null!;

}

public class Bar
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question and added classes to use, and I would appreciate if you could update your sample with the same, to make it easier to both follow and elaborate around. Also, for your "JsonValueKind.Array", it can very well hold nested object and I can't see how those will be processed in your code sample. Shouldn't the array items be recursively passed to "PopulateObjectWithJson"? For me, an array of items is just yet another set of objects, arrays and value types. I can't parse into known list/array etc. types as I don't know what they might be.

Comment: @Asons It's almost morning here (night owl me haha) so I probably won't be checking anytime soon. As I stated in the comment, you will need to call the function recursively instead of just create an object like my sample. I just wanted to demo how to assign the array for your case. Hopefully you already solved it tomorrow when I am back, if not I can try again (ping me if I forget).

Comment: I'm not in a hurry here, and will wait a few days, to get some more answers before starting to study them, so you will have time to update ... and good, more complete code samples I often reward with a bounty :)

Comment: I added a solution using Reflection instead of relying on JSON. Please see if it's good enough, or you require a JSON solution? I think I can add this code into your original question as well.

Comment: It's okay. Sorry my job is quite busy recently so I cannot follow up with this question anymore. Hope you found a good solution. Good luck.