# Is there a similar approach to CustomCreationConverter in System.Text.Json?

Tags: system.text.json

I have used CustomCreationConverter in Newtonsoft.Json for many years. Nowadays, I am trying to migrate to System.Text.Json. Is there a similar approach? I just want to add something in the method "Create".

Comment: There is no ability to do that currently.  Also `PopulateObject()` is not currently implemented, see [.Net Core 3.0 JsonSerializer populate existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56835040/3744182).  If you can describe what you need to do in your converter perhaps we can suggest workarounds.

Comment: @dbc Please check out my [repo](https://github.com/popyoung/HugeHard.JsonConfig/blob/main/HugeHard.JsonConfig/JsonConfig.cs) and jump to line 108.

Comment: Could you do your `SetHost()` in an [`IJsonOnDeserialized.OnDeserialized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserialized.ondeserialized?view=net-6.0) or [`IJsonOnDeserializing.OnDeserializing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserializing.ondeserializing) callback?

Comment: @dbc Thanks for your advice. However, there was no way to pass a parameter to the class JsonConfig when JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonConfig> was called, although I implemented the interface you mentioned. Finally, I substituted a global variable Application.OpenForms for the parameter. This approach is not so elegant, and can have some latent hazards, so I am still expecting some way to optimise it.