# C# Convert.ChangeType() int to enum

Tags: c#, reflection

With the following model:

```cs
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public WorkingLevel WorkingLevel { get; set; }
    // ...
}

enum WorkingLevel
{
    Unknown,
    Level1,
    Level2,
    Level3
}
```

and the following view model:

```cs
public class PatchResourceVM
{
    public List<PropertyValue> PropertyValues { get; set; } = new();
}

public class PropertyValue
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have an ASP.NET controller action like this which is supposed to updated properties of a person resource:

```cs
[HttpPatch("{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePerson(int id, PatchResourceVM model)
{
    var person = await _dbContext.Employees.FindAsync(id);

    if (person is null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    foreach (var propVal in model.ProrpertyValues)
    {
        var propertyInfo = person.GetType().GetProperty(propVal.PropertyName);
        if (propertyInfo is null)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Property {propVal.PropertyName} does not exist");
        }

        var oldValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(person, null);

        try
        {
            Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType;
            object? safeValue = (propVal.Value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(propVal.Value, t);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(person, safeValue, null);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            return BadRequest($"{propVal.Value} is not a valid value for {propVal.PropertyName}");
        }
        // from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41466710/19363672

        var changeLog = new PersonChangeLog
        {
            PersonId = id,
            // ...
            PropertyName = propVal.PropertyName,
            OldValue = oldValue?.ToString(),
            NewValue = propVal.Value
        };

        _dbContext.Add(changeLog);
    }

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return NoContent();
}
```

When I want to update an enum I get the `InvalidCastException` exception.

Payload:

```js
{
  "propertyValues": [
    {
      "propertyName": "WorkingLevel",
      "value": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response: `"1 is not a valid value for WorkingLevel"`

The code works fine for numeric and string types, but I cannot update the enum properties.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent JSON patch and auditing? There's libraries that solve this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using reflection, the value of an enum can be set to its underlying type, so you can use `ChangeType(Object, TypeCode)`.

```
object? safeValue = (propVal.Value == null) ? null : 
                    Convert.ChangeType(propVal.Value, Type.GetTypeCode(t));
propertyInfo.SetValue(person, safeValue, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

For enums you can use static methods provided by `Enum`:

```cs
var value = "1";
if (type.IsEnum)
{
    var tryParse = Enum.TryParse(type, value, out var result); // todo analyze tryParse
    Console.WriteLine(result); // prints "Level1"
}
```

But in general I would suggest to look into reusing some tools for patching endpoints either using [JSON Patch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ([JsonPatch.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPatch.Net/) for `System.Text.Json`) approach or using tools like Automapper to map from dictionary for example (a bit similar to something done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68184979/2501279))

Answer (score 0):

"Because enums aren't IConvertible, which is required for Convert.ChangeType:  "For the conversion to succeed, value must implement the IConvertible interface, because the method simply wraps a call to an appropriate IConvertible method."

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7b0703fb-701a-412e-ba5a-dd878813cc2c/improvement-suggestion-convertchangetype-should-convert-stringint-into-enums?forum=netfxbcl

This will solve your enum issue:

```
object? safeValue = ( propVal.Value == null )
    ? null
    : ( t.IsEnum
        ? Enum.Parse (typeof ( string ), propVal.Value.ToString() )
        : Convert.ChangeType ( propVal.Value, t )
    );
```