# C# - How to join data from two generic types together

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to join two types together (like doing .AddRange in a list) using for example reflection?
Something like in this reponse https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702650/13112059, but here the data from the target object gets replaced.

```
public class ItemsResponse
{
    public List<Items> Items{ get; set; } = new List<Items>();
}
```

In my case I receive a response from an API and cast the data to this type for example which is only defined at runtime, but then I also need to do another request where I receive data from the same type and I wanted to join this objects together to return them as one.

Example of a request:

```
public static async Task<T> Query()
{
    var response = new T();
    var response2 = new T();
    response = (T)await RequestAsync(); // First request
    /// ...
    response2 = (T)await RequestAsync(); // Second request
   // I want to return an object containing data from the two responses
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "cast the data to this type for example which is only defined at runtime"? I don't really understand how that is supposed to work.

Comment: My bad, I added an example. In my real code I have that call twice and I wanted to somehow have both results in only one object.

Comment: given the code there must be `MyClass<SomeClass>.Query()` somwhere. Then do something like `MyClass<SomeClass>.Query().Concat(MyClass<SomeClass>.Query())`

Comment: Yes there is, but I want to return the complete object from this method. Maybe now is more explicit @Firo

Comment: if you just want to get an object back containing two responses then either build a type that matches your data shape or return the two objects as a `Tuple` - that way you can get both responses when querying.

Answer (score 1):

A generic type parameter, i.e. `<T>` is *not* a runtime type. The type is still statically known, just not by this particular piece of code. Sooner or later you have to supply an actual type for your `T`, this might be done in some third party code, but it will still be known at compile time. Ofc, it *might* be defined at runtime, but that is not really relevant here.

If you want to create a list of responses you just need to include the generic type parameter in any classes or methods that handles these types.

```
public static List<T> MakeRequests<T>(MyRequestObject obj){

    var items = new List<T>();
    items.Add(obj.Query());
    // Do more queries, or whatever else you want
    

    return items;
}
```

You cannot really *use* the returned objects from your query, other than putting them in a collection, or converting them to `string` or `object`. So generic code like this is typically limited to fairly simple things that needs to be done regardless of the actual type.

Collections may include things like tuples, i.e. `(T Request1, T Request2)`, but you cannot combine two object into an object of the *same* type, at least not without a horrible amount of reflection.