# How i can get all standard colors from colors or brushes classes

Tags: c#, colors

How i can get all standard colors from colors or brushes classes?

For example a thing like :

```
Foreach var item in  brushes
     Do something...
```

Comment: You can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571982/iterating-over-class-properties).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach(var color in typeof(Brushes)
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
{
    var currentColor = color.GetValue(null) as Brush;
}
```

If you want just color names then you can use `LINQ`:

```
 var colorNames = typeof (Brushes)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Select(x => x.Name);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)).Cast<KnownColor>().ToList();

var color = Color.FromKnownColor(colors[0]); //for ex.
```

or directly

```
var colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)).Cast<KnownColor>()
                    .Select(k => Color.FromKnownColor(k))
                    .ToList();
```